# SPRESENSEに接続したSDカードが認識できない

Tags: spresense

失礼致します。
タイトルの通り、拡張ボードに接続したSDカードが認識できていない状況です。
SDカードを接続後に下記の操作を試したのですが、どちらからもSDカードが認識できず困っています。

・拡張ボードへUSB接続を行いWindows環境でSDカードが認識できるか検証（通電は確認済み）
・メインボードへUSB接続後、Ubuntu上のSpresense SDK環境にて各種操作を行った後にシリアルターミナル上でSDカードが認識できるか検証

マイコンボードに触れる機会が初めてなので知識・経験不足で恐縮ですが、全くわからんので知恵をお貸し頂ければと思い書き込みました。
解決に繋がる情報を頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

【実施環境】
・SPRESENSE
メインボード
拡張ボード

・micro SDCard
SanDisk Extreme 32GB
FAT32
パーティション設定なし

※サンプルプログラムは実施できました。

Answer (score 2):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答いたします。

SDカードが認識しないのは、SPRESENSEのメインボードと拡張ボードを接続するコネクタの接触の問題と思われます。

メインボードを上からしっかりと押し込むことで、コネクタの接触が改善し、SDカードへのアクセスが可能になると思います。お試しください。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

「結構加圧したけどな。。。」と思いつつも、メインボード全体を今までよりも強めに加圧したところ、わずかですが押し込まれた感がありました。その後PCに接続したところドライバのインストールが開始され無事にSDカードを認識する事が出来ました。
精密機器に慣れていないので、思い切りが欠けていたようです。お騒がせしました。。。

無事に解決する事が出来て良かったです。ご対応ありがとうございました。