# SDカードが認識できない

Tags: spresense

タイトル通り拡張ボードに挿入したSDカードが認識できません。
[他の質問者の解決方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49296/19110)であるメインボードと拡張ボードの接触も疑いましたが、どうやっても認識できません。
また、メインボード側ではシリアルポートに/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUARTが出てきますが、拡張ボード側（メインボードと接続）では出てきません。接触不良以外に原因はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ＳＤカードがＰＣからストレージとして認識できないということでしょうか？

その場合は、SPRESENSEにマスストレージとして動かすためのスケッチを書き込まないと認識されません。

スケッチの例の"SDHCI"の中に”UsbMsc.ino”というスケッチがあるので、それを開いてコンパイルをして、SPRESENSEに焼きこんでみてください。

プログラム実行後に、シリアルコンソールで以下のメッセージが見えれば、ＳＤカードを認識しています。

```
\*\** USB MSC Prepared! ***
Insert SD and Connect Extension Board USB to PC.
```

ＳＤカードを認識していない場合は、以下のメッセージが出て失敗します。

```
SD card is not present
USB MSC Failure!
```

その後、**拡張ボードの側のUSBポートにケーブルを差し込む**とSDカードがストレージとしてＰＣから見えます。
試してみてください。

Comment: 言われた通りやってみたところできました。助かりました、ありがとうございます。